# Fuelphp rest PUT issue

Tags: put, fuelphp

framework - fuelphp 1.7

i try to upload file from server to another.

to send i use curl.

```
$url = "http://files.loc/api/upload";

$body = 'data that I want to send';

$fp = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:256000', 'w');
if (!$fp) {
    die('could not open temp memory data');
}
fwrite($fp, $body);
fseek($fp, 0);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($body));

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

receiving data on the other server looks like

```
class Controller_Api_Upload extends Controller_Rest {

    public function put_index()
    {
        $content = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $file = fopen('./images/txt.txt', 'w+');
        fwrite($file, $content);   
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

i have 403 error "Access forbidden!". what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of webservers by default only accept GET and POST, and you need to enable PUT, DELETE and PATCH. Perhaps this is the case here too?